# How to customize highchart treemap datalabels?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, treemap

This is my treemap. I have 3 levels and I want to customize the labels like the provided picture.

[image: Edit treemap-heatmap]

to be more specific I want:

1. **In the first level** I want to have the first level labels out of the main box on the top and the second level should hide here.
2. **After drill down** in the second level I want to have the labels again out of the main box.
3. **In all levels**, I want to see the last level details in labels as shown in the sample image.
4. And is there a way to have 3 levels but just drill down into 2 levels?
5. And do you know why the colors change after drill down? the colors are not the same in the first level and third level!

Thanks a lot for your consideration.

[image: This].

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve exactly. Probably it is not possible with `highcharts` without customization. Regarding the last point, I set `color: "transparent"` for the main levels and colors look correctly: https://codesandbox.io/s/treemap-heatmap-te8bv

Comment: @WojciechChmiel Yes this solved my number 5 problem thank you 

Comment: @WojciechChmiel I just wanted to customize the labels. I don't know how to take the labels out of the box. I think It's possible with highchart because I saw the developed examples but I don't have access to the code, unfortunately!

Comment: You can render those labels with Highcharts.SVGRenderer yet on the attached picture it looks like some points are grouped under the label and this is not supported out of the box. API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer

Comment: @WojciechChmiel I have found the solution I will post it here soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by @WojciechChmiel the solution for the color difference problem is to set the parent color as `transparent`!

for having labels outside of the section box I used `data label format function`. In `react` the `renderToString` helped me to pass the react component as a title for levels.

I also could recognize the level of each label by:

```
  const { level } = data.point.node;
```

with this, I could manage which desirable label to display!

-Running demo provided below!

[image: Edit treemap-heatmap-solution]